# What are all the films in Colonel Sandurz's collection?

Tags: reference, spaceballs

In *Spaceballs*, Colonel Sandurz uses the *Spaceballs* film itself to find where the princess is. During that scene, we see Colonel Sandurz's film collection has many films:

[image]
[image]

A few are quite easy to spot, like the *Rocky* series (up to Rocky XIV) and *Friday the 13th* on the left side of it and *Spaceballs* in the top shelf.

But what is the full list of all the films in Colonel Sandurz's collection and which film/franchise do they refer to?

Comment: Many of those that show the front artwork appear to be other Mel Brooks films.

Comment: Trivia, also they are easy to read.

Comment: @cde I don't think they are all easy to read and don't agree on trivia part either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, **all these movies are previous works of [Mel Brooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Brooks#Filmography)**. As we have already identified Rocky I to XIV and Friday the 13th. Others are

**Top Rack**

1. [Spaceballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceballs)
2. [To be or Not to Be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Be_or_Not_to_Be_(1983_film))
3. [High Anxiety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Anxiety)
4. Mel Brooks The History of the World Part 1
5. [Young Frankenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Frankenstein)
6. [Blazing Saddles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazing_Saddles)

**In Middle Rack**

7. Spaceballs
8. To be or Not to be
9. [History of the World Part 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_World,_Part_I)
10. High Anxiety
11. Silent Movie
12. Young Frankestein
13. Possibly [The Muppet Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Muppet_Movie)
14. [The Producers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Producers_(1968_film))
15. [The Twelve Chairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Chairs_(1970_film))

**Bottom Rack**

16. Rocky (I-XIV)
17. Friday the 13th (I-XIV)

Answer (score 7):

The full list appears to be:

#### Bottom Shelf

- Friday the 13th (I-XIV)
- Rocky (I-XIV)

A joke about the seeming never-ending sequels

#### Middle Shelf

Then the top shelves appear to be multiple copies of several of Mel Brooks other films:

- [The Producers (1967)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063462/) two copies
- [The Twelve Chairs (1970)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066495/)
- [Blazing Saddles (1974)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071230/)
- [Young Frankenstein (1974)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072431/)
- [Silent Movie (1976)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075222/)
- [High Anxiety (1977)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076141/)
- [History of the World: Part 1 (1981)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082517/)
- [To Be or Not To Be (1983)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086450/)
- [Spaceballs (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/)

#### Top Shelf

On the very top shelf are multiple copies of these same Mel Brooks titles. There appear to be three of each directly above the copy below it (except for History of the World: Part 1 which only has two copies on the top shelf).

**NOTE:** there are some other films shown in other shots with white and yellow labels but their titles are not legible.

Comment: And if you want to be complete, two different releases of Young Frankenstein and To Be.

Answer (score -2):

Everything seen is easily legible and identifiable as multiple copies of the entire Mel Brooks collection of directed movies to date (Space Balls inclusive), and 14 fictional copies of the Rocky Balboa series and of the Friday the Thirteenth series.